# How to prevent my formula from skipping the cell when i insert new row

Tags: excel, row, formula, skip

here is my sample
`=IF(C4="R",E4,0)+IF(C5="R",E5,0)+IF(C6="R",E6,0)+IF(C7="R",E7,0).........`

then if i insert new row between C4 to C5, my formula skips from C4 to C6

Here:
   `=IF(C4="R",E4,0)+IF(C6="R",E6,0)+IF(C7="R",E7,0)........`

`.  |  C   |    D    |  E`

`4  | "R"   |  ...   |  14`

`5  | "T"   |  ...   |  5`

`6  | "R"   |  ...   |  6`

`TOTAL "R" = 20`
`TOTAL "T" = 5`

Column C is drop down list  each  row you can select: "R", "T", "K".....

hoping some people help me. Thanks You very much..
`i cannot post image coz it needs 10 reputation...`

Comment: Looks as if you should simply use `=SUMIF(C4:C10,"R",E4:E10)`.

Comment: Also, instead of `C5`, you can use `OFFSET(C4,1)`. Similarly change every other cell except for ones on the 4th row.

Comment: Thank you very much but maybe i can't use the sum formula bcoz, i make my cell depends on what category/type i should sum. ex. c4 become "T" then it should be sum up with same category.

Comment: Thank you sir, i used SUMIF method. God Bless!!!

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to post the Excel sheet with a little more detail on what your trying to achieve...meanwhile if your inserting rows but always want the SUM to be based on C4 then change to $C$4 etc adding the $ Char will lock the sum in place

if you send the sheet it maybe wiser you use a helper column with vLookup or Sumifs..

Answer (score 0):

`=SUMIF(C4:C6,A7,E4:E6)`

`C4:C6 is category range`
`A7 CELL where i make a reference for total of "R"`
`E4:E6 is the value of each category.`

Thanks AXeL Richter!